# numbers to days of week

Tags: r, date

I already converted full dates (2/22/2022 is a Tuesday, so it shows as 3) to numbers (Sunday=1, Monday=2, ect..) Now I'm plotting using facet_wrap and it shows all the graphs labled as "1", "2", ect.... How can I get the labels of each one "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday," ect?

Comment: See [How to make a great R reproducible example](
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Why create numbers? Pull out the day label in a column: `your_data$day_of_week = lubridate::wday(your_data$date_column, label = TRUE)`. Then use that column.

Comment: That would work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `labeller` for the `facet_wrap()`. It's quite straightforward.  This is some dummy data to show how to set them up:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(day = 1:4, 
             run1 = runif(4)*100, 
             run2 = runif(4)*100, 
             run3 = runif(4)*100) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-day)


# Labeller for facet titles - Set up a named vector
  day_labeller <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
  names(day_labeller) <- 1:7


# Plot
  ggplot(df) +
    geom_col(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = day)) +
    facet_wrap(~day, labeller = labeller(day = day_labeller))
```

[image]